# TYPO3 6.2 / 7.x Forum extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Is there any working Forum extension for TYPO3 6.2. 
I have tried mm_forum with some patches, but id does not work.
I have also looked at extension repository but without any luck. 
Any help is welcome :)

Comment: tt_board is a very small and simple forum extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new forum extension from Mittwald is typo3_forum (6.2 und 7.x)

Link in Typo3-Repo: http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/typo3_forum

How to migrate your mm_forum to typo3_forum:

- Install **typo3_forum**
- Execute the Scheduler Task **Database Migration**
- Open your root TypoScript Template Record and include **typo3_forum**'s static TypoScript
- Change your TypoScript configuration (e.g. in your template extension or Typoscript records) from **plugin.tx_mmforum** to **plugin.tx_typo3forum**
- Uninstall **mm_forum**
- Clean up the database using the Install Tool "compare" functionality.
- If you have custom fluid templates for the forum using the forum's ViewHelpers you have to adjust the namespace declaration accordingly. E.g. **{namespace t3f=Mittwald\Typo3Forum\ViewHelpers}**

Answer (score 0):

You could check the [multiblog-extension](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/multiblog), it´s up to date and ready for TYPO3.CMS 6.2.

Comment: Oh sorry, but you should try to contact the Mittwald support itself, i heard and read in some chat´s that they work on a new version. They also run mm_forum under TYPO3 6.1, if you can read german here is the [comment >> LINK](http://www.typo3.net/forum/thematik/zeige/thema/118012/)